# 1/4 of the graphical layout shows when it is emulated

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, servlets

app  worked perfectly till I decided to download eclipse kepler to allow my android app the connect via a servlet to a webapp..., suddenly a 1/4 of the graphical layout shows when it is emulated

activity_main:
[image: activity_main]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.cosmoteapp.MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/Sign_In"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="59dp"
                android:layout_height="59dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </TableRow>

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datEvent"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="0"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="Email" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Email Address"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="0"
                 android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="Password" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cmdValider"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Confirm->Ok"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cmdCpte"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:text="New Account"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

when emulated shows:
[image: emulator's]

Comment: *app worked perfectly till*  no it was not .... I think that main problem is that  you made new emulator with small screen (and this layout always do not fit for such size) ... replace `RelativeLayout`  with `ScrollView` ... now you will be able to scroll down the layout to the last button ... you may also try to dissable the appbar/toolbarfor this activity ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you try to see many views on small screen device.I't not Eclipse problem, but virtual device parameters. Try to use Nexus 5 emulator and you would find that it works fine.

**SOLUTION:** Replace your your actual main `ViewGroup` with nested `RelativeLayout` into`ScrollView`.

After change, your actual code should look like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.example.cosmoteapp.MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/Sign_In"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </TableRow>

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datEvent"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_span="0"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="Email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Email Address"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_span="0"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="Password" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cmdValider"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Confirm->Ok"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cmdCpte"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:text="New Account"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**NOTE:** according to comment:

> is android studio any better? i think i need to spend few hours on
>   size of emulator and in size....

Yes, that's a way better than eclipse because from `layout manager` you can see how your app looks on every nexus or some additional custom devices. If you would use `Android Studio 2.0 Beta 2` from `Cannary channel` updates, you would could use function `instant run` (or similar name), so you changed something in layout click run and instantly saw it on emulator. It's very useful!

Your time is limited, so search for tools which would speed up your development. Give Android Studio 2.0 a try and tell me what you think.

Comment: thx for helping!, i added a <horizontalScrollview> in between to see layout to last..., but weird ....eclipse luna read size differently... i have tried to re-size avd as before but unsuccessful, emulator (in) screen still way too large

Comment: create a copy of project and run an copy in `Android Studio`

Comment: is android studio any better? i think i need to spend few hours on size of emulator and in size....